# Display multiple lists in SenchaTouch2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have some JSON data, something like this

```
category:Fruits
 item:Banana
 item:Apple
 item:Peach
category:Vegetables
 item:Cucumber
 item:Tomato
```

And for this data I want to display 2 lists with vbox layout, like this

```
|  Friuts  |   Vegetables  |
----------------------------
|  Banana  |   Cucumber    |
|   Apple  |    Tomato     |
|   Peach  |               |
```

Of course, the data is getting from the server and lists count and items can vary.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you meant `HBOX` layout here. Just access the JSON data by an Ajax request, access individual list and use `setData()` function of List to populate the lists with individual category data.